# Como subir una imagen desde Vue a una app graphql django?

Tags: django, vue.js, fileupload, graphql

Codigo de la mutation:

```
class AgregarImagenCategoria(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.ID()
        file = Upload(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()

    def mutate(self, info, file, id):
        categoria = Categoria.objects.get(id=id)
        categoria.image = file
        categoria.save()
        return AgregarImagenCategoria(success=True)
```

Codigo del metodo Vue:

```
onAdvancedUpload(){
      let data = new FormData();
      const name = uuidv4();
      data.append('operations', JSON.stringify({"query":"mutation ($file: Upload!, $id: ID!) {\\n  uploadFile(file: $file, id: $id) {\\n    success  }\\n}","variables":{"id":1,"file":null},"operationName":null}));
      // data.append('operations', '{"query": "mutation ($id: ID!, $file: Upload!) { uploadFile(id: $id, file: $file) { success } }", "variables": {"id": "1", "file": null}}');
      data.append('map', '{"1":["variables.file"]}');
      data.append('1', this.file, `${name}.${this.file.name.split('.').pop()}`);
      return axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:81/graphql/`, data, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      }).then(response=>{
        console.log(response)
      }).catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
```

Favor de brindar ayuda o correccion, cuando ejecuto el metodo me da el error Must provide query string. Si hubiera otra forma igual la acepto, no solo axios.